# When should I use 'path' over 're_path'?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Here is an example from [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/):

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index, name='main-view'),
    path('bio/<username>/', views.bio, name='bio'),
    ...
]
```

```
from django.urls import include, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^index/$', views.index, name='index'),
    re_path(r'^bio/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.bio, name='bio'),
    ...
]
```

From my understanding `path` syntax is more readable and offers the angle brackets that can catch information from the URL and convert a type.

Should I use `re_path` **only** when I need a regular expression and use `path` for all other cases?

Answer (score 29):

[`re_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#re-path) is an implementation of the ['old' way of handling urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#example), which was previously (version <2) done by [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.url) from `django.conf.urls`.

*See the paragraph in [Django 2.0 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#whats-new-2-0) about this.*

This being said, **I recommend using [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#path) whenever you can!**

The reasons I see:

1. `path` was introduced with the goal of making things simpler, which is clearly the direction the Django devs want to go. So, when using `path` you are following this direction, thus minimizing the risk of having to adapt your codebase to new changes.
2. While `path` is not just a result of an attempt of making things simpler, it actually really does make things simpler and more readable, which is a good reason alone to why `path` should be preferred if both choices are an option.

Now `re_path` exists for reasons, so there are cases when using `re_path` might still be a better option. One scenario is clearly when require very customized converter and reach the limit of what is feasible with [custom converters for 'path'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters). Yet another scenario to use `re_path` could be when upgrading a system with rather complex url-converters form a Django 1.x to a 2.x: Simply replacing the `url` with `re_path` commands can be much more time-efficient and thus be a desirable approach.

Answer (score 2):

You got it. The newer `path` syntax makes for much cleaner URL patterns. You can [write your own path converters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters), too, so that more of your paths can use `path` instead of `re_path`.